How to update the safe global version?
We need to implement relay to pay the gas fee from the safe ( global) , and we need to update the safe version how we can ? from UI we can not ?
https://docs.safe.global/sdk/relay-kit

You could use Safe CLI to do this. Please note that as of now you can only update to v1.3.0 using the CLI, as updating to later versions is not yet supported by the CLI.
Hope it helps; Best, Louis

How i can update to the latest version @Louis

You need to wait for CLI to support it; if it is urgent and you are a technical person, you can also use this contract to migrate from v1.3.0 to v1.4.1. Please be aware though that this code is not audited and that the manipulation could lead to loss of funds, so only proceed in this path with care and if you know what you are doing  https://github.com/safe-global/safe-smart-account/blob/main/contracts/libraries/Safe130To141Migration.sol

The Safe130To141Migration.sol contract that Louis is referring to appears to have been replaced by a generic SafeMigration.sol migration contract as of September 2024: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-smart-account/blob/main/contracts/libraries/SafeMigration.sol
